# Two different widths on two different browsers

Tags: html, css

hello guys i have a div which contains a link and a div , i gave a width of 70% to the link and a width of 30% to the div (summing it up to 100%). its working fine in chrome , but its not working in safari ..the width property of the link is not taking any effect in safari.Please help

```css
.rec-p-b {
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
}
.rec-p-b1 {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #02020294;
    border: 1px solid #034039;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="recomment_profile_b_view">
  <a target="_blank" href="" class="recomment_pro_button rec-p-b">Profile View</a>
  <button class="recomment_button rec-p-b1">
    <img src="images/recommend.png" alt="recomment">
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: because a link is an inline element, am not sure how you think it's working. It's not working at all even on chrome

Comment: but its working in chrome ,

Comment: but it's not :)

Comment: what should i do to make it fit inside a box side by side?

Comment: use inline-block

Comment: There's no second div, I only see a button.

Answer (score -1):

- The link tag is an inline element, so you should set it `display: block`, or `inline-block`, or `float: left` to floating it as block element.
- You had added the padding beside adding the width, the total size will be equal `padding` + `width`. To fix it, you should add `box-sizing: border-box;` to your css to merge the with as 100% of the size:

  ```
  .rec-p-b {
      float: left;
      width: 70%;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 0px;
      padding: 7px 10px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .rec-p-b1 {
      float: left;
      width: 30%;
      background-color: #02020294;
      border: 1px solid #034039;
      border-radius: 0px;
      padding: 0px 5px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  ```

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem is the padding you add. Try use `box-sizing: border-box`

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box }

.rec-p-b {
    width: 70%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
}
.rec-p-b1 {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #02020294;
    border: 1px solid #034039;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="recomment_profile_b_view">
  <a target="_blank" href="" class="recomment_pro_button rec-p-b">Profile View</a>
  <button class="recomment_button rec-p-b1">
    <img src="images/recommend.png" alt="recomment">
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Apply display: block to anchor tag
Apply following properties to both(anchor & div):
box-sizing: border-box;
float: left;